# Python converting ip address to ip number?

Tags: python, formatting, ip

I am iterating over a range of ips to extract the organization name associated with them from Maxmind database. I want to start from the first ip in ip space, and say continue till when ips have the same organization name and then print the range!

```
def incrementIP(ip):
    if ip == '224.0.0.0':
        return 'end'
    nip = struct.unpack('>I', socket.inet_aton(ip))[0]  # This line convers IP string to number
    nip += 1
    ip = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('>I',nip)) # This line converts the number back to IP
    return(ip)

d = {}
IPaddress = '0.0.0.1'
while IPaddress != 'end':
    org = (gi.org_by_addr(IPaddress))
    d.setdefault(org,[]).append(gi.range_by_ip(IPaddress))
    IPaddress = incrementIP(gi.range_by_ip(IPaddress)[1])
```

and here is the error I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                    
 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-a010e0aa70ac> in <module>()
      4     org = (gi.org_by_addr(IPaddress))
      5     d.setdefault(org,[]).append(gi.range_by_ip(IPaddress))
----> 6     IPaddress = incrementIP(gi.range_by_ip(IPaddress)[1])
      7 #     print (d)
      8 

<ipython-input-14-0b40331de68c> in incrementIP(ip)
      7     nip = struct.unpack('>I', socket.inet_aton(ip))[0]  # This line convers IP string to number
      8     nip += 1
----> 9     ip = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('>I',nip)) # This line converts the number back to IP
     10     return(ip)

error: 'I' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295
```

I cannot find sure why I am getting this error. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: The error seems to indicate that the 'I' formatted number is either negative, or larger than 4294967295. Can you test whether that's the case?

Comment: @L3viathan is there a way that I would be able to print the one that has the error, or the last one without printing all of them/?cause they are a lot and would take a lot of time

Comment: just add a line before line 9 like `if not (0 <= number <= 4294967295): print number`